# Getting error: flutter/flutter.h' file not found

Tags: flutter

In Xcode:

[image]

[image]

```
Xcode build done.                                            7.3s
Failed to build iOS app
Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
/Users/ngocanhluu/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.8+2/ios/Classes/messages.g.m:7:8

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 15.
```

in Android studio

Comment: Please do not post your code as images. **Code is text** and can be copied, pasted and otherwise manipulated. **Images are static** and cannot. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77184370/edit) and include all of your code as properly formatted text.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following these steps to resolve this:

1. Make a backup of the ios/Runner folder.
2. Delete the ios directory.
3. Run `flutter create (project_name).` at the project level. (this will recreate your ios folder).
4. Paste your Runner backup into the project's iOS folder of the project.
5. Verify/Update the Version, the Bundle ID, and all the information in Runner.xcworkspace (in the iOS folder).